# Intellij open file / open class popup slow to complete search

Tags: intellij-idea

Kind of annoying. I mean, I want to Command O type the file and hit enter, not wait for the result, and then enter. If press enter before it will usually open up some other file.

This used to be way faster in previous versions of Intellij. Is there a way to tune this?

Comment: I believe it is called new.search.everywhere. all things new are great :/

Comment: I might have been able to disable the new search and using the old one, but unsure if search is faster.

Comment: Performance problem report is welcome: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: Please insert a screenshot. maybe I could help you.